# ‘Every continuous real-valued function on $X$ achieves a minimum’ is a topological property.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Suppose that a topological space $X$ has the property that every continuous real-valued function on $X$ takes on a minimum value. I need to show that any topological space that is homeomorphic to $X$ also possesses this property.

We don't know anything else about the topological space other than this.

Intuitively, it makes sense to me because homeomorphisms preserve open sets, and thus topological properties. It seems to me that boundedness should be a topological property.

However, I have no idea where to even begin with proving this. Please help!

Comment: If $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism and if $f:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f\circ F$ is continuous. Thus it attains a minimum.

Comment: @JessyCat Continuity.

Comment: BTW, such spaces are called "pseudocompact". For metric spaces it's equivalent to usual compactness. In general it's not. (we could ask for a maximum too, if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a topological space, homeomorphic to $X$. Let $\phi:X\to Y$ be an homeomorphism. Take any continuous function $f:Y\to \Bbb R$. Then $f\circ\phi$ is a continuous, real valued function from $X$, and it takes on a minimum value, but since $f\circ\phi$ and $f$ take on the same values, $f$ also takes on a minimum value (the same).

Comment: probably a stupid question, but how do you know that $f \circ \phi$ and $f$ take on the same values?

Comment: It is a question.... but why not try to prove it yourself?  It uses some property in the definition of "homeomorphism".

Comment: Take any value $f(y)$ taken on by $f$. There is some $x\in X$ such that $\phi(x)=y$, so $f\circ\phi(x)=f(y)$.